# QML TableView disable horizontal scrollbar

Tags: qt, qml

I am using `TableView` QML component. I have 3 columns in there. Each column width is set to the table total width divided by 3. This introduces some fraction parts and in result, a horizontal scrollbar is always visible in the bottom:

[image]

I would like to disable this scrollbar but can't figure out how to do it. I am using QML `TableView` from QtQuick.Controls 1.4 (the old ones). Qt version is 5.12.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [horizontalScrollBarPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) to `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff` to hide the horizontal scrollbar